# How to format the result from ConversationAnalysisClient response

Tags: .net, botframework, orchestration

We are using Orchestrator workflow of Custom question answering service for  connecting to multiple Question answering service.

We are fetching the predictions using ConversationAnalysisClient. The response contains all data but to access the values we need to use json. Below code is not woring in .net ,

dynamic conversationalTaskResult = response.Content.ToDynamicFromJson(JsonPropertyNames.CamelCase);
dynamic conversationPrediction = conversationalTaskResult.Result.Prediction;

Question answering is returning the data in KnowledgeBaseAnswer format which is easy to access. Is there any possible way to fetch the Question answering response from Orchester as KnowledgeBaseAnswer or which has a correct readable format.